# Spring Hibernate lazy load behavior

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making a web based app in spring/hibernate. In database I am using onetomany and manytoone relations. I have manytoone relationship in users for location and onetomany relationship for users in location. In both entities I have lazy loading option turned on. As per my understanding if this is turned on, the database query to get the location should not be executed until explicitly called for it but whenever I do a get from the userdao the below query is executed which makes me think that even after having the lazy option turned on it is retrieving the location information. Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong or is this the expected behavior.

```
Below is my user entity code

package com.kwisque.database.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = true, length = 32)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = true, length = 128)
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private Integer active;

    @Column(name = "PROVIDER", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String provider;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_ID", nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="USER_LOCATION_INFO", 
               joinColumns={@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")}, 
              inverseJoinColumns={@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID")})
    private Location location;

   // @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   //   @JoinColumn(name = "SPECIALIZATION_ID", nullable = true)

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="USER_SPECIALIZATION_INFO", 
               joinColumns={@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")}, 
               inverseJoinColumns={@javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name="SPECIALIZATION_ID")})
    private Set<Specialization> specialization = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(final String userId, final String name, final String password, final String emailId, final Integer active, final String provider, final Set<Role> roles, final Location location) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.active = active;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(final String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(final Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(final Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(final String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(final String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(final Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}


Location entity code

package com.kwisque.database.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION")
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7153748534015057865L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "LOCATION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer locationId;
    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private String zipCode;
    @Column(name = "STATE_ABBR", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private String stateAbbr;
    @Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private double latitude;
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private double longitude;
    @Column(name = "CITY", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = true, length = 132)
    private String state;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "location")
    private Set<User> users;

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(Integer locationId, long longitude, String city, long latitude, String zipCode, String state,
            String stateAbbr, Set<User> users) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.stateAbbr = stateAbbr;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return this.locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<User> getUser() {
        return this.users;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setUser(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return this.zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getStateAbbr() {
        return this.stateAbbr;
    }

    public void setStateAbbr(String stateAbbr) {
        this.stateAbbr = stateAbbr;
    }
}


Query being executed at my get from USerDao

Hibernate: select user0_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_3_0_, user0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE2_3_0_, user0_.EMAIL_ID as EMAIL_ID3_3_0_, user0_.NAME as NAME4_3_0_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD5_3_0_, user0_.PROVIDER as PROVIDER6_3_0_, user0_1_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION1_4_0_, roles1_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_3_1_, role2_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID2_5_1_, role2_.ROLE_ID as ROLE_ID1_1_2_, role2_.NAME as NAME2_1_2_ from USERS user0_ left outer join USER_LOCATION_INFO user0_1_ on user0_.USER_ID=user0_1_.USER_ID left outer join USER_ROLE roles1_ on user0_.USER_ID=roles1_.USER_ID left outer join ROLE role2_ on roles1_.ROLE_ID=role2_.ROLE_ID where user0_.USER_ID=?
```

Comment: Well, as the query shows, nothing is loaded from the location table. So lazy loading seems to work as expected.

Comment: I do see these two strings in the query. user0_1_.LOCATION_ID as LOCATION1_4_0_USERS user0_ left outer join USER_LOCATION_INFO, what does this mean then?

Comment: Hibernate needs to know if the user has or dosn't have a location, and what its ID is, in order to initialize the user.location field to null, or to a lazy proxy containing the ID of the associated location. So it needs to do a join with the join table USER_LOCATION_INFO.

Comment: Got it, makes it much more clear now.

Comment: To complement on @JBNizet's comment, note that there is `left outer join USER_LOCATION_INFO` which is supposedly a light weight join-table and did not join to the `LOCATION` table.

Comment: thanks for the information.